# Using Dataframe cell values to style another Dataframe with same dimensions

Tags: python, pandas, styling

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'foo bar foo'.split(),
               'B': 'one one two'.split(),
               'C': np.arange(3), 'D': np.arange(3) * 2})

j = [{'bgcolor': "#55aa2a"}, {'bgcolor': "#d42a2a"}, {'bgcolor': "#d42a2a"}]
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'E': j, 'F': j, 'G': j, 'H': j})
```

The code above produces two dataframes, `df1` is a standard frame and `df2` is a frame composed of dictionaries (each cell has a dictionary as its value).

I want to use the cells of `df2` to style the cells of `df` in place, i.e. the cell `df[0,1]` will take the value of cell `df2[0,1]` and use it as its style

Example:

```
def highlight(df,df2):
    df[0,1] = '{}'.format(df2[0,1])
    return df
```

(except applied to the entire frame)

This should give the background color of `df[0,1]` as `df2[0,1]="55aa2a"` but returns a `KeyError` after calling `df = df.style.apply(highlight, df2=df2).render()`

Is it possible to use the cells of `df2` to style the cells of `df1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change format of values for strings and then return DataFrame with same columns names (index values is necessary same too):

```
df2 = df2.applymap(lambda x: 'background-color: {}'.format(x.get('bgcolor')))
print (df2)
                           E                          F  \
0  background-color: #55aa2a  background-color: #55aa2a   
1  background-color: #d42a2a  background-color: #d42a2a   
2  background-color: #d42a2a  background-color: #d42a2a   

                           G                          H  
0  background-color: #55aa2a  background-color: #55aa2a  
1  background-color: #d42a2a  background-color: #d42a2a  
2  background-color: #d42a2a  background-color: #d42a2a  

def highlight(x):
    d = dict(zip(df2.columns, x.columns))
    return df2.rename(columns=d)
```

Or:

```
def highlight(x):
    return pd.DataFrame(df2.values, columns=x.columns)
```

---

```
df.style.apply(highlight, axis=None)
```

[image: df]

Comment: Perfect! your code in the section `In [26]:` did exactly the job! Thanks

How does this adjust if there are multiple values in the dicts of `df2`?