# Finding specific bgcolors in dataframe to style another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54330809/using-dataframe-cell-values-to-style-another-dataframe-with-same-dimensions) is a question asked that will help to style a dataframe using dicts that are in the cell of another dataframe. It works well when there is only one `bgcolor` attribute in the dicts but how can this be applied when a cell has more than one `bgcolor`?

Here is code to create dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'foo bar foo'.split(),
           'B': 'one one two'.split(),
           'C': np.arange(3), 'D': np.arange(3) * 2})

j = [{'bgcolor': "#55aa2a", 'bgcolor':"#d4d400"}, {'bgcolor': "#d42a2a"}, {'bgcolor': "#d42a2a"}]


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'E': j, 'F': j, 'G': j, 'H': j})

**df2 = df2.applymap(lambda x: 'background-color:{}'.format(x.get('bgcolor')))**
def highlight(x):
    return pd.DataFrame(df2.values, columns=x.columns)
df.style.apply(highlight, axis=None)
```

This code will fail at the line closed in ** because there is a cell that has two `bgcolor` attributes and the `get` function is returning a `dict` and not just a single value.

Is is possible to slice the dict to only get one `bgcolor`?